# How to pop out an image inside a ul li div when the css surrounding it won't let you

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image inside an ul li container.

Here's the simple code:

```
<div class="rm_wrapper">
    <div id="rm_container" class="rm_container">
        <!-- Start Image List -->
        <ul>
            <li data-images="rm_container_1" data-rotation="-15">
                <img class="parentImage" src="artwork/book-covers/cover1small.png" />
            </li>
            <li data-images="rm_container_2" data-rotation="-5">
                <img id="cover2" src="artwork/book-covers/cover2small.png"/>
            </li>
            <li data-images="rm_container_3" data-rotation="5">
                <img id="cover3" src="artwork/book-covers/cover3small.png"/>
            </li>
            <li data-images="rm_container_4" data-rotation="15">
                <img id="cover4" src="artwork/book-covers/cover4small.png"/>
            </li>
            <li data-images="rm_container_5" data-rotation="0">
                <img id="cover5" src="artwork/book-covers/cover5small.png"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I role over that image that's insider the LI, I want to simply have that image come forward in time, grow bigger and when you mouseout, the image returns to its normal state.

Note, cover1small.png is 164 x 240 and the larger/clearer image is 400 x nnn meaning it'll be sized proportionately.

Here's the balance of the code: for the UL

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="rm_container_1">
        <img src="artwork/book-covers/cover1.png"/>
        <!-- <img src="images/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/7.jpg"/> -->
    </div>
    <div id="rm_container_2">
        <img src="artwork/book-covers/cover2.png"/>
        <!-- <img src="images/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/7.jpg"/> -->
    </div>
    <div id="rm_container_3">
        <img src="artwork/book-covers/cover3.png"/>
        <!-- <img src="images/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/7.jpg"/> -->
    </div>
    <div id="rm_container_4">
        <img src="artwork/book-covers/cover4.png"/>
        <!-- <img src="images/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/7.jpg"/> -->
    </div>
    <div id="rm_container_5">
        <img src="artwork/book-covers/cover5.png"/>
        <!-- <img src="images/5.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/6.jpg"/>
        <img src="images/7.jpg"/> -->
    </div>

</div>
```

This is a modification on the CODROPS article: here --> http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/28/rotating-image-slider/

What I am eliminating is the "arrows" on the right and left, the play/pause button so all you have is the main part showing the first "cover" images that are tilted.

I'm doing a website for launch of a graphic novel and all I want to do is make it so when I roll over or click, the image will pop forward and OUT of the boundaries of the UL LI constraints.  what I get is the larger image confined to the 165 x 240 cover image.

Thanks everyone, the launch is june 1st so time is of the essence.  If you need more code, everything I'm doing is in the CODROPS link.

UPDATE: This is what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/css/css3-zoom-animation/css3-hover-zoom1.html

Bottom line: The cover photo is NOT hir-res but the photo I want to go to "is".

This is the effect I want to achieve when mouse over happens:

```
 .rm_container ul li .parentimage {  
   -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all .3s ease-out;
   transition: all .3s ease-out;
 } 
 .rm_container ul li .parentimage:hover {
   -moz-transform: scale(4);
   -webkit-transform: scale(4);
   -o-transform: scale(4);
   -ms-transform: scale(4);
   transform: scale(4);
 }
```

It's got to look "cool" but simple.

Ah, here's my plunker that's a mock of what I'm trying to do.

[Plunker Example](http://embed.plnkr.co/jKiUn02xKFgYeX4TEeRc/preview)

Comment: You're going to need to provide an MCVE (minimum complete verifiable example) of the issue in jsfiddle before anyone can help you. Right now there isn't enough CSS for anyone to determine exactly what is happening on your end of the code, but I suspect it isn't anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the off chance this is what you're looking for, it can be done with jquery:

https://jsfiddle.net/z896hdhL/2/

The fiddle above contains runnable code to see what this example would do. The code below is a psuedo example of how your implementation would look.

Example html:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="small.jpg" class="small"></img></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.small, .large {
   transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
.large:hover {
    transform: scale(4);
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".small").on("mouseenter", function(){
    var $large = $("<img src=\"large.jpg\" class=\"large\"></img>");
    $(this).replaceWith($large);
});
```